# Image gallery with lighbox in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to achieve the gallery with lightbox and food menu on this website http://demo.bootstraptemple.com/italiano/ using Wordpress. However, I am using advanced post type but I don't know how to get them to display the lightbox and the menu. Below is my code.

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'gallery',
            'orderby'   => 'post_id',
            'order'     => 'ASC'
        )
    );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
            the_post_thumbnail();
    endwhile;
?>
```

The above is what I did for the food gallery with lightbox and using the same concept for the food menu as well. Kindly advise me on how to get it fixed.

Comment: where you save gallery images? you use a plugin? custom field? Seems you call featured image

Comment: @mariobros am using Advanced Custom Fields. However, am able to pull the images out. but making the lightbox work is where the issues is. as i have to pass two images one a small version and a big one that shows on the lightbox. Any idea how to fix this ???

Comment: @mariobros Yes Advanced Custom Fields

Comment: the images are saved in the db i guess

Comment: Ok, you use acf or acf repeater? Is possibile to display screenshot of field you have setting in acf?

Comment: sure. Beside using ACF do you know of any other way to do this.

Comment: Ok , if you show me a screenshot of acf configuration, i could you give you a response;-)

Comment: here is the screenshot of my settings https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbhe2ahrq3ggs47/Screen%20Shot%202017-01-14%20at%2012.55.26.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you storing images as custom fields for each post? Assuming your code is showing the images, all you need to do is include a script and wrap the image in a <a> tag with the relevant class. You can also add classes to the image by passing attributes through the function you're using: the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'example' ) ); I use this jQuery plugin: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: so, if i get you right i can have something like this

 if ( has_post_thumbnail() )
            the_post_thumbnail,(array('class' => 'example'));


?>

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-6">
 <div class="item">
                      <?php
                                if (has_post_thumbnail())
                                    the_post_thumbnail();
                                ?>
 <a href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/assets/img/bg01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Image Caption" class="has-border">
                                        <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

Comment: Sorry for bugging yu with plenty question but how do i display the lightbox image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has not been precise in the explanation, however:

If you storing X images in one post by acf repeater, you have to code this:

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'gallery',
        'orderby'   => 'post_id',
        'order'     => 'ASC'
    )
);

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):

      while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();

          the_sub_field('sub_field_name'); //return image url or image object as you want
     endwhile;

    endif;
endwhile;
?>
```

If you store one image per post, you have to code this:

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'gallery',
        'orderby'   => 'post_id',
        'order'     => 'ASC'
    )
);

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   echo '<img src="' . get_field('acf_image_field_name') . '" alt="" />'; //if your field retgurn url instead of object
endwhile;
?>
```